# CodeIgniter 3 : URL on fetched data

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I'm just wondering how can I create a page with the URL on fetched data.

For example

```
chapter.php?bookid=135&chapter=Chapter_1
```

So what I need is to create a page with the data (from other tables) based on the bookid and chapter.

Comment: Your question is not clear. I guess you are looking for uri segments in Codeigniter: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html . Describe your issue well

Comment: @JobSam yes i just learned the basic about URI segments. thank you :)

Comment: Welcome  @Pedro Ordonez :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get database data for book

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data

```
public function get_data() {
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('yourtablename');
  $this->db->where('bookid', $this->input->get('bookid'));
  $query = $this->db->get();

  return $query->row();
}
```

Then on controller

```
$book_result = $this->model_book->get_data();

$data['bookname'] = $book_result->bookname;

$this->load->view('some_view', $data);
```